# Inverse of the transformation $X \mapsto Y = X\cdot X^t$

Tags: matrices, transformation, linear-transformations

I have a Matrix Y of Kind : $n\cdot I$  where $I$ is the identity Matrix of size  $n\times n$  , I need to find Matrix $X$ if it exists such that all elements are either 1 or -1 and satisfies $XX^t$ = $Y$.
Please Help

Comment: Any ideas? Did you try anything?

Comment: What field is $Y$ over?

Comment: I tried recursive program that is efficient only till n=5

Comment: @Paul all elements of X must be 1 or -1

Comment: Try figuring out if there are any values of $n$ for which this is impossible. That might lead you to a way to construct $X$ when it does exist.

Comment: i determined it for n= 3 ,5  it is impossible, while possible for n=1,2,4, i cannot determine further

Comment: Do you understand why it’s impossible for those values of $n$?

Comment: No :/  . Still makeing observation but unable to determine.

Comment: If every element of $X$ is $\pm 1$, then every element of $XX^t$ will be the sum of $n$ $\pm 1$’s. Does that help?

Comment: These are few of the possible cases for n=4  : http://ideone.com/v00xyk

Comment: One observation is that no of -ve terms can be either  nx(n-1) /2   or (n+1)xn /2

Answer (score 0):

To get $XX^T=nI$, you need

(1) The columns vectors to be orthgonal,

(2) with length $\sqrt{n}$

If each entry is -1 or 1, (2) will always be satisfied.  Also, the inner product between column vectors will be odd or even, based on whether n is odd or even.  An odd n therefore will never work.  N has to be even.  you just have to set them up as mutually orthogonal.

Comment: can you suggest reference or some idea to generate n mutually orthogonal vectors or length N such that all have coordinates -1 or 1